# SpannableString With Different Languages in the same TextView

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable

Let's say, I have a TextView in a ListView.

The value of the TextView Is Name(in Arabic) + "Shared" +Name(in English).

English as you Know starts from Left to Right But Arabic starts from Right to Left

When the Both Names are written in English its working Fine

but when the first name is in Arabic  its will be like this

"Shared"+ Name(in English)+ Name(in Arabic)

I tried AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)

but its Not Working

Here is my code :

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(PostUserName_ + " " + share + " "
                + uname.trim());

        ClickableSpan FirstName = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onFirstName(v, position, 3);
                }
            }

        };

        ClickableSpan LastName = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onLastName(v, position, 3);
                }
            }

        };

        ss.setSpan((new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE)),0, PostUserName_.length() + share.length() + 1+uname.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ss.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(context,
                android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small), PostUserName_.length(),
                PostUserName_.length()+share.length()+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        ss.setSpan(FirstName, 0, PostUserName_.length() ,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ss.setSpan(LastName, PostUserName_.length() + share.length() + 2,
                PostUserName_.length() + share.length() + 1+uname.length()  ,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.8f), PostUserName_.length() + 1,
                 PostUserName_.length()+share.length() + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, PostUserName_.length() + share.length() + 1+uname.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        holder.PostUserName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.PostUserName.setText(ss);
```

Answer (score 1):

with any arabic text it is liable to default to RTL layout, to force LTR you can do this:

eg. a format string for combining three strings with spaces between:

```
<string name="three_args_with_spaces_ltr">\u202D%1$s %2$s %3$s\u202C</string>
```

those unicode chars force the LTR behaviour
for more info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Bidirectional_General_Formatting

Answer (score 0):

If possible use two TextViews for english and arabic and align them left and right..

Comment: its not good because i have to calculate the length of the first name and the last and if the first name is long i have to make the second name under the first name and if the second name was long i have to do that to but if the both names are short i have to put them is the same line

Comment: If you use two TextView you can change their position programmatically so i think its possible Jehad

Comment: LayoutParams paramsNotSingleLine = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
LayoutParams paramsSingleLine = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   yourTextView.setLayoutParams(paramsSingleLine);// this textView will take whole line next will be in next line
   yourTextView.setLayoutParams(paramsNotSingleLine);// this textView will allow another textview in same line

Comment: i will try this but my textView is an item of a listview

Comment: inside getView() method of your list adapter you can implement this